# How to automount USB drive synchronously on Debian Buster? Is it safe?

Tags: debian, usb-drive, automounting, synchronization

I hate it when I copy a large file (~2 GB) to an USB drive and it shows a "fast" progress bar, only to wait indefinitely afterwards, until the copy is finally done. So I'd prefer to mount with the `sync` option, which makes the progress bar not lie to me about remaining time (the overall difference in speed is negligible).

Question is: how to add the `sync` option to the automount on Debian 10?

I haven't found much answers to that, and what I have found is from 6 to 10 years ago (recommending packages that don't exist anymore, such as `usbmount` or `gnome-volume-properties`).

Other concern are (really old) messages about `sync` [destroying the USB stick](http://readlist.com/lists/vger.kernel.org/linux-kernel/22/111748.html). Is this still a reality?